# I am getting error: Expected a value of type 'Iterable<dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null' while fetching the data from api in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working flutter project and trying to fetch the data from api

code:

url ="https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/6405e540c0e7653a05834f86"

loadData() async{

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final catalogJson = response.body;
final decodedData = jsonDecode(catalogJson);
var productData = decodedData["products"];

CatalogModel.items = List.from(productData).map<Item>((item) => Item.fromMap(item)).toList();
setState(() {});
```

}

I am getting data upto **decodedData** in terminal But when I try to go for **productData** I am getting **NUll** in return.

Comment: https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/6405e540c0e7653a05834f86 In this API products is under the key of "record" your cannot get products directly

Comment: Try `final productData = decodedData['record']['products'];`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

This is how your json looks like. The parent element is record and inside record you have your products. It should work if you use `['record']['products']` instead of `['products']`